# Using multiple mapper inputs in one streaming job on hadoop?

Tags: python, hadoop, streaming

In java I would use:

> MultipleInputs.addInputPath(conf, path, inputFormatClass, mapperClass)

to add multiple inputs with a different mapper for each.

Now I am using python to write a streaming job in hadoop, can a similiar job be done?

Answer (score 3):

You can use multiple -input options to specify multiple input paths:

```
hadoop jar hadoop-streaming.jar -input foo.txt -input bar.txt ...
```

Comment: Thank you. But what if i want different mappers for these different input path? I actually got different data sources, from which the data I want to parse to the same format so that reducer can process.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with Streaming as I am with normal HMR, so I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this, but you could run your inputs through their Mappers with identity Reducers, then take the output of those jobs and use them as input for another job with an identity Mapper and the needed Reducer.

Comment: So if I want to use multiple output for multiple input, should I rewrite hadoop-streaming.jar? Or just specify input and output as shell parameters?

Comment: Hi, How can i provide multiple input through templeton or webhcat api?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this can help you: https://github.com/hyonaldo/hadoop-multiple-streaming.

Here you can see "different mappers for these different input path" as well:

```
hadoop jar hadoop-multiple-streaming.jar \  
  -input    myInputDirs \  
  -multiple "outputDir1|mypackage.Mapper1|mypackage.Reducer1" \  
  -multiple "outputDir2|mapper2.sh|reducer2.sh" \  
  -multiple "outputDir3|mapper3.py|reducer3.py" \  
  -multiple "outputDir4|/bin/cat|/bin/wc" \  
  -libjars  "libDir/mypackage.jar" \
  -file     "libDir/mapper2.sh" \  
  -file     "libDir/mapper3.py" \  
  -file     "libDir/reducer2.sh" \  
  -file     "libDir/reducer3.py"
```